# SAPUI5 XMLHttpRequest() bad Method 405

Tags: javascript, file-upload, ftp, xmlhttprequest, sapui5

I try to upload a image on my FTP-Server, therefore I have created a function:

```
    sendpic: function () {
        [...]

        var data = new FormData();
        data.append(image, "img");
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'MYFTPURL', true, 'MYFTPUSER', 'MYFTPPASSWORT');
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.send(data);     
    },
```

If I debug this message in the browser I get the following message:

**Screenshot from Browser Debug Error**

[image]

**Console error messages:**

- Error Message 1

  [image]
- Error Message 2

  [image]

The results of my research are, that the server may have not activated the `XMLHttpRequest()` method `send()`. Is this a possibility. 
Or are there any other things i have to consider?

Comment: FTP servers aren't HTTP servers, so using an HTTP request to do this makes no sense (and nor does getting an HTTP error message back from a request to an FTP server).

Comment: You've obscured so much data about the request that I have no idea what is actually happening. It could be a preflight OPTIONS request for all I know.

Comment: Maybe it is a POST request though, but how should we know why your server is rejecting it? You've not shown any of the server side code.

Comment: `data.append(image, "img");` — You said you were trying to upload an image, but that's a string. Where is the image you are talking about?

Comment: "The results of my research are, that the server may have not activated the XMLHttpRequest() method send(). Is this a possibility. " — No. (a) It is activated by the client and (b) YOU GOT A RESPONSE TO THE REQUEST!

Comment: At first: Thanks for your response. I am having a canvas where i am drawing a picture. I can download this canvas/image locally on my pc -> this is working already ... to take it to the next step, i am trying to upload the image on an ftp server. Therefore i have organised an ftp server from a webhoster (i have no server-side coding) and i thought i can upload the image with the code above. What do you recommend?

Comment: Using HTTP and not FTP (you can't achieve what you want with FTP). You need server-side code to handle the file upload.

Comment: OK. What do you think about this one (http://ftp.apixml.net/)? Its a JS Code with whom i can upload to FTP. Do think this will work? How do i use HTTP to upload files to a server?

Comment: "What do you think about this one?" — What one?

Comment: "How do i use HTTP to upload files to a server?" — Form. File input. Server side programming language of your choice. (At the most basic approach).

Comment: First question - I've added a link to the question. Second question: Overall: Coding  a form for uploading my file in Javascript on client side and a data receiver in php on server side?

Comment: `ftp.apixml.net` — That uploads the files over HTTP to a third party to whom you give the keys to your FTP server. They don't appear to ask for anything in exchange. The phrase "Dear god no, I don't want to be hacked" comes to mind.

Comment: OK. Then i try to do it with http and server-side programming...Do you have a little instruction guide for this programming? (I have never done this bevor)

Comment: No. Pick a programming language. Find an introductory tutorial for server-side programming with it.

Comment: But it is possible to upload image-files to a external ftp-server. I means with external, that it is not the same server where the app will be deployed?

Comment: You could write server-side code that would do that. FTP is a weird choice of technology to use anywhere in the process, but it is possible.

Comment: What would you recommend else(i think http.. I'm not fit in that)? I need a technologie to upload created data on a server or somewhere, where someone else can download it...i also thought about using google drive for uploading, but i think this would be way to complicated...

Comment: HTTP would be a sensible option. Google Drive would also be a sensible option … it uses HTTP. SFTP would be a sensible option.

Comment: Do you have any experience with using google drive api in such situation?

Comment: No, but its standard OAuth and then a well documented API.